# how to use JavaScript and and php to store a variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a success function that has some data stored inside it:

```
function(receiverUserIds) {
console.log("IDS : " + receiverUserIds.request_ids);
}
```

this will log: IDS :123123213, 4645646654, 7897987989, ....

what i want to do is grab all those id's and store them in the database.

one way i was thinking to do it is by using ajax:

```
    function(receiverUserIds) {
        console.log("IDS : " + receiverUserIds.request_ids);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
            friends_invite: receiverUserIds.request_ids,
            success: function(msg){
                /* alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); */
            }
        });
}
```

and on the same page:

```
if(isset($_POST['friends_invite'])){
print_r($_POST['friends_invite']);
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

something might be wrong with either the ajax or i don't know. maybe you guys can suggest another way of doing this..??

any ideas?

Thanks

edit: if i enable the alert `lert( "Data Saved: " + msg );` i get an alert so i know that the ajax is successful, but i don't see my `$_POST` being echoed out

Comment: This method should work.  Define `doesn't seem to work`.  What happens?  Can you post a snippet of what the code looks like when you view source in your browser after it has been generated?

Comment: As the javascript being written out with php?  If not, `_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` is unavailable.

Comment: if i enable the alert lert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); i get an alert so i know that the ajax is successful, but i don't see my $_POST being echoed out

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending information back and forth with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008291/sending-information-back-and-forth-with-ajax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should work fine.  First thing that sticks out is that you should be using the `data` option to pass the data.  See the [specs of the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { friends_invite: receiverUserIds.request_ids },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Use fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or something to track what data is flowing back and forth instead of just saying "doesn't work".  What doesn't work?  What's happening?  What's not happening?  Why?  Go through the process step-by-step systematically and see how far the data is going before something fails.

Comment: if i enable the alert 'alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );' i get an alert so i know that the ajax is successful, but i don't see my '$_POST' being echoed out

Comment: This happens with or without the change I suggested in my post (or both)?

Comment: actually with your change i get this in the alert
 `Data Saved: Array(
  [0]=>123123123
  )`

Comment: So the data is now being passed.  That's what you wanted right?

Comment: yeah, but i cant get it in php, that is more important

Comment: What do you mean?  The alert is displaying the result of `print_r($_POST['friends_invite']);`... that's what `msg` is in `success: function(msg)`.  So you are getting it, and sending it back to JavaScript by printing it to the response.  It's very clearly there because then JavaScript echoes it.  You just need to do something constructive with `$_POST['friends_invite']` on the PHP page :-)

Comment: Hope that makes sense!  Also, it looks like it's not coming through as an array correctly... there is only one entry on the PHP side but you are passing a set of 3 id's, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
friends_invite: receiverUserIds.request_ids
```

I don't belive JQuery works this way. It would have to be changed to something like:

```
data: 'friends_invite=' + receiverUserIds.request_ids
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this-

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
            'data':{friends_invite: receiverUserIds.request_ids},
            success: function(msg){
                /* alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); */
            }
        });
```